# Erro no item.addeventlistener

Tags: html

```
<script>
    const list = document.querySelectorAll('.list');

    function activelink() {
        list.forEach((item) =>
            item.classlist.remove('active'));
        this.classlist.add('active');
    }
    list.forEach((item) =>
        item.addeventlistener('click', activelink));
   
</script>
```

Dizendo que o item.addeventlistener não tem função.

Comment: Já tentou `addEventListener`? O javascript é uma linguagem que diferencia entre letras maiúsculas e minúsculas.

Comment: ja tentei porem veio com outro erro

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tomei a liberdade de fazer alguns ajustes...

```
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.list');
      list.forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener('click', (evento) => {
          evento.target.classList.toggle('active');
        });
      });
```

Como já citado, tenha atenção no que é maiúsculo e minúsculo, isso faz toda a diferença.

Eu não entendi o que você quer fazer de fato pois o título da pergunta é muito vago, porém, o trecho de código acima pode ser uma luz.